# External HDD in USB 3.0 case unmounts on sleep

Tags: macos, usb, external-hard-drive, sleep, connection

## Afterword AKA Edit#2:

Another long period later, I finally got around to making a sleep script and applying sleepwatcher as a launchd daemon.
That's how it looks - rc.sleep:

```
diskutil eject DSRD
```

Seem pretty easy after 3 days of making it work :D

But back to the topic. The daemon works just fine. And that scares me.
Because it does - I found out that the whole thing didn't matter. The case is so broken, that after ejecting it becomes inaccessible, but continues to draw power and rotating the disk.

I'm just gonna go buy a new case.
With those words I find my answer to the question.

Thanks for help and all!

P.S. Watch out for disk compatibility with Macs people!

---

## article.txt.old:

For starters, I haven't tried it on anything but my MacBook Air (10.11). I know I should have, but I can't.
Further details:

1. The disc: [Hitachi 5K500 B-320](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlVFs.png), named DSRD
2. USB 3.0 case: [LogiLink UA0106](http://www.logilink.eu/showproduct/UA0106.htm)
3. Stock cable

### The problem:

The disc is connected, and Mac goes to sleep. When I wake it up there are two things that might happen:

1. OS X will spit out a notification that it has been detached (and the disc is not apparent in the Disc Utility), although it is still connected.
2. The Mac won't wake up until I force restart or pull out the disc cable.
3. I am currently listening to music, and nothing happens. When the disc is being used the problem does not occur.

I checked the System Prefs. in the Power Saving and unticked "sleep discs when possible" - didn't help.

What I also tried to do was to keep the motor spinning:

```
while true
do touch /Volumes/DSRD/touchy.log
sleep 10
done
```

It works just fine, but I'm concerned about the discs lifespan. Also, sleep values like '60' don't work.

I think that sums up my situation. Posting this with hope that someone knows something about that, or has a different solution. Or maybe I am missing something? ;)

Thanks in advance, have a nice day.

-Votar

#### [Edit]

I should have mentioned that the disc is formatted in OS X Extended file system.

Comment: According to the [Data Sheet](http://www.logilink.eu/showproduct/UA0106.htm) for that enclosure it is only supported in Windows, no mention of OSX. See Download section in your link for Data sheet.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @Moab, I sure missed it. But sadly, the questions remains, if anyone has ever encountered it before and if so, how to deal with it (not the expensive way).

Comment: Can you try other enclosures to see if they act the same way, this would verify if it is the enclosure's problem or in OSX

Comment: I shall try it sometime, although not too fast with my current finances :D
Thanks for the idea though.

Comment: Borrow a usb external drive to test.

Comment: unticking sleep discs when possible will not help. Since the computer is going to automatically turn off power to the usb ports when it sleeps/hibernates to save power. Using a powered usb hub may prevent this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing a Google image search on that enclosure, it's using a non-standard A-type connector.  That's not even the official USB Super Speed logo on the case.  A proper USB enclosure should be using a B-type connector.  If the device breaks that standard, it makes me wonder what other standards they also broke.

It apparently doesn't conform properly to the USB power management spec either, so the only way to avoid this annoying (and dangerous) error is to unmount the disk before your computer sleeps, and mount it again after it wakes.

Fortunately, you might be able to use an open source program called [SleepWatcher](http://www.bernhard-baehr.de/) to automate this for you.  The program is a daemon that can automatically fire scripts when your MacBook sleeps and wakes.  [This forum thread](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20080329201951648) has a good write-up on what scripts you should run.

To summarize, you basically need two scripts in the root of your home directory; `~/.sleep` and `~/.wake`.

**.sleep:**

```
#!/bin/sh
osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to eject (disks where free space â‰  0)'
```

**.wake:**

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/sbin/diskutil list | grep -e ' \+[0-9]\+: \+[^ ]\+ [^ ]\+' | sed 's/.*\(disk[0-9].*\)/\1/' | xargs -I{} /usr/sbin/diskutil mount {}
```

---

The product page for that SleepWatcher tool says it works on OS X 10.10 (Yosemite).  No word as to whether it works on 10.11 (El Capitan).  I have not personally used this program before so I cannot vouch for how well it works.  The only "real" solution to your problem is to spend some coin on a proper USB enclosure.

Comment: OK, so some time passed, but the problem reminded about itself.
First off, thanks for the way around. I checked whether unmounting via diskutil does the job and I say - it works so far. I will try to understand the mechanism behind the SleepWacher and fix it that way. Also, I think it would be easier to just `diskutil mount` on wake and `diskutil unmount` on sleep, just because I'm completely lost in your way of thinking.